# I don't know where is my mistake at the appcompat:design:1.1.0

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, material-components-android

## appcompat:design:1.1.0

I don't know where is the mistake. Probably at `appcompat:design:1.1.0` but idk what I've done wrong. I am new btw :)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the error log?

Comment: remove androidx.appcompat:design

Comment: **Could not find androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0.
Required by:
    project :app
Search in build.gradle files** @Dhruv

Comment: If you want to use Design Support Library for androidx   
 use this `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

Comment: actually this is the answer. thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library `androidx.appcompat:design` **doesn't exist**.

**Remove** this dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0'
```

and add the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

> Material Components for Android is a drop-in replacement for Android's Design Support Library.

**Add** one of these dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' //stable release
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' //stable release
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03' //alpha release
```